# Why is my use of install.packages giving me dependency errors when I try installing tidyverse-packages?

Tags: r, tidyverse

As of 18 Nov 2021, I've downloaded all the tar.gz files that tidyverse imports/depends/suggests. I'm working on a RedHat OS and, unfortunately, I don't have an Internet connection to this machine.  I have all those files in a folder.  Then I use this command

```
  install.packages(
    # i use setwd() to make my tar.gz directory equal to my current working directory
    destdir = ".", 
    pkgs = c(...), # I list all relevant tar.gz here, e.g. c("foo_tar.gz", "bar_tar.gz") 
    dependencies = c("Depends", "Imports", "Suggests"), 
    quiet = FALSE, 
    repos = NULL
  )
```

But I get this error message

```
ERROR: dependencies ‘broom’, ‘cli’, ‘crayon’, ‘dbplyr’, ‘dplyr’, ‘dtplyr’, ‘forcats’, ‘googledrive’, ‘googlesheets4’, ‘ggplot2’, ‘haven’, ‘hms’, ‘httr’, ‘jsonlite’, ‘lubridate’, ‘magrittr’, ‘modelr’, ‘pillar’, ‘purrr’, ‘readr’, ‘readxl’, ‘reprex’, ‘rlang’, ‘rstudioapi’, ‘rvest’, ‘stringr’, ‘tibble’, ‘tidyr’, ‘xml2’ are not available for package ‘tidyverse’
```

Every one of those files are in my working directory.  I'm using R version 3.6, which is compatible with the downloaded version of tidyverse. Why can't the installer find these files?

Comment: Is there a reason you're downloading the tar files directly as opposed to just using install.packages with CRAN?

Comment: Unfortunately, the system that I'm using has no connection to Internet.  That's why I'm using this route.

Comment: Did you install those packages it lists before trying to install tidyverse? Unfortunately dependencies aren't quite as easy for the system to resolve when you're installing from local files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to run `tools::write_PACKAGES` before executing `install.packages`.

Even though the tar.gz files are in the same folder, the PACKAGES file must be populated to properly account for dependencies.  Otherwise, the install.packages function doesn't know how the packages are related.  Would be nice if that error message was more specific.